# Open neighborhood in Lie group

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

The following is from "An Introduction to Lie Groups and Lie Algebras" by Kirillov.

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group and $U$ be a neighborhood of $1$.  Then if $H$ is the subgroup generated by $U$, $H$ is open because $h\cdot U$ is a neighborhood of $h$ in $G$.

I am not seeing why the last part is true.  If the product in $G$ were an open map it would be clear that $h\cdot U$ is a neighborhood of $h$, but why is it true anyways?

Comment: The map $x \mapsto hx$ is a homeomorphism $G \rightarrow G$ (continuous with continuous inverse).  The image of $U$ under this homeomorphism is $hU$.

Comment: Ah, the product **is** an open map from $G\times G$ to $G$ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication by $h$ on the left is a homeomorphism from $G$ to itself.
In particular, $U$ open implies $hU$ open.

Comment: I'm confused why it's a homeomorphism.  Doesn't the definition only say that multiplication $G\times G\rightarrow G$ is a smooth map?

Comment: See the comment by D_S. One only needs that $G$ is a topological group.

Comment: Ah I see; that's what I was missing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $h\in H$, and $L_h(x)=hx$. Since $L_h$ is a diffeomorphism, it is an open map. We deduce that $L_h(U) =\{hu, u\in U\} \subset H$ is open. Since
 $h=h. 1\in L_h(U) $, we deduce that $H$ contains an open neighbourhood of $h$ and henceforth is open.